# PHP OOP proper class communication

Tags: php, oop, class, communication

Is there a ***good practice*** way of making communication between classes?

For example, I have a CMS I'm working on. In **main** class it instantiates two new Classes ***ThemeManager*** and ***ModuleManager***. Now, I need my *Theme Manager* to be able to access *Module Manager* so that it can read loaded modules and print their content in a page.

Is this *OK* ? Making these two classes public properties of **main** class. This enables me two-way communication (which I don't necessarily need in this situation):

```
class MainClass {
    public $ThemeManager;
    public $ModuleManager;

    ..........

    function instantiate_managers() {
         $this->ThemeManager = new ThemeManager($this);
         $this->ModuleManager = new ModuleManager($this);
    }
}
```

Or is it this better? Passing one already instantiated to another, since one-way communication will do *OK* for my purpose:

```
class MainClass {
    private $ThemeManager;
    private $ModuleManager;

    ..........

    function instantiate_managers() {
         $this->ModuleManager = new ModuleManager();
         $this->ThemeManager = new ThemeManager($this->ModuleManager);
    }
}
```

Note that in either way I have to pass these references further to *Module* class and *Theme* -> *Layout* classes.

Maybe it would be better to declare **ThemeManager** and **ModuleManager** in global scope since they will be instantiated only once anyway and saves me the trouble of passing their references through each **__*construct*** ? I've read somewhere that this is bad practice in OOP and I'm trying to avoid it, but in situations like these this seems like the *least* hacky way to do it.

Is there a 4th good way to handle communication which I haven't tought about?

## Answer

I ended up using [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) for **dependency injection** method since it felt most *natural* and was suggested in both answers.

Comment: I can see why the theme manager should 'know' the module manager? By why the other way around?

Comment: It shouldn't, I said that one-way communication works just fine in this case. Actually all 3 ways **work** , I'm just looking for **proper** one if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for, is the best way to do [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

There's many ways to approach it, but in your specific case I would say: Go for option #2.
Since your theme needs to be aware of the module, but not the other way round, this will solve your problem in the easiest fashion.

But: don't consider this a 'general answer' for dependency issues in the future. The best way to think about it, is each case individually.

Two more ways to do this:

1. Instead of passing things in the constructor, you can create individual set methods. (e.g.: `setModuleManager`).
2. You could also use a dependency injection container.

Number two may seem appealing when you learn about. It's simple and central; but I would still be wary. It's a bit of a sledgehammer, and may actually cause you to create too tight dependencies. (loosely coupled is considered a very good thing).

setter methods or constructor arguments force you to be extremely explicit, and I feel it's the best way to learn this stuff.

Comment: Any message about why this deserved a down-vote would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think someone in here hates the idea of dependency injection, doh.

Comment: Somebody keeps downvoting answers without even providing a 1-row critique. I don't find that helpful at all.

Comment: @Flavius I guess GolezTroll gave us a hint with his nickname.

Answer (score -2):

All your approaches sound bad. I could detail on this, but I honestly think that you'd learn best by reading a book on OOP, and then start using a modern PHP (5.3+) framework like ZF2, to get a feel for how it's done.

**Dependency injection**, highly modular, MVC, it's all in there for you to learn from.

However, within the limitations of your initial design, I would do it like this:

[image]

Where an `Application` object coordonates the rest of the components. Please note the `Application::render()` method which could return the entire html generated by the page.

Although I repeat, I do not think that you mean *the right thing* when you say "module" or "theme". You should really have a look at a modern PHP framework (PHP 5.3+) and see how software engineers have chosen to design these things.

You are missing for instance the notion of *routing*.

Comment: Not an answer. If you feel this way, you can add a comment and/or close-vote the question for being 'not constructive'.

Comment: The question is about learning proper OOP, isn't it? I honestly and openly think that my proposal is a good approach to learning.